# How to set a mask in component ngx-intl-tel-input

Tags: angular8

How to define a mask for the phone number according to the format presented by the placeholder attribute of the ngx-intl-tel-input component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for me. My ngx-intl-tel-input component is an angular formControl. So, I used the valueChanges event of this formControl to aply a mask:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.confirmForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  cellPhone: [{ number: this.currentUser.number, countryCode: this.currentUser.countryCode }, [Validators.required]],
  code: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
  id: [this.currentUser.id]
});

this.confirmForm.get("cellPhone").valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
  //aply the mask
})}
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate on how in the world you managed to do this? Cos I couldn't...

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps

```html
this.confirmForm.get("cellPhone")!.valueChanges.pipe(
      throttleTime(200),
      tap((x)=>{
        if(x?.number){
          let nums = x.number.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})/);
          if(nums) {
            let masked = !nums[2] ? nums[1] : '' + nums[1] + ' ' + nums[2] + (nums[3] ? ' ' + nums[3] : '') + (nums[4] ? ' ' + nums[4] : '');
            this.confirmForm.get("cellPhone")!.setValue(masked);
          }
        }

    })).subscribe((x: any) => { });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).